# Access nested property by path

Tags: javascript, jquery, properties, nested

I'm trying to access to nested properties of an object from a string.

Here is my sample code :

```
var obj = {
  'text': 'hello',
  'foo': {
    'float': 0.5,
    'bar': {
      'id': 42
    }
  }
};

var keyOne = 'text';
var keyTwo = 'foo.float';
var keyThree = 'foo.bar.id';

console.log(obj[keyOne]); // successfully log 'hello'
console.log(obj[keyTwo]); // trying to log '0.5'
console.log(obj[keyThree]); // trying to log '42'
```

I'm trying to do it in JS but I also have jQuery ready for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to do a little bit of traversal for that.

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the path by it's `.`, then [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) over the parts with each iteration accessing the property it refers to via a [bracket-notation accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

Eventually you'll reach the value you're after.

```js
var obj = {
  'text': 'hello',
  'foo': {
    'float': 0.5,
    'bar': {
      'id': 42,
      'baz': [{ name: 'Mary' }, { name: 'Jane' }]
    }
  }
};

var getValueByPath = (obj, path) =>
  path.split('.').reduce((acc, part) => acc ? acc[part] : undefined, obj);

var keyOne = 'text';
var keyTwo = 'foo.float';
var keyThree = 'foo.bar.id';
var keyFour = 'foo.bar.baz.1.name';

console.log(getValueByPath(obj, keyOne));
console.log(getValueByPath(obj, keyTwo));
console.log(getValueByPath(obj, keyThree));
console.log(getValueByPath(obj, keyFour));
```

Comment: WOW so beautiful and powerful ! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with accessing like this? is there a reason you need the keys to be defined in variables?

Hope this helps :)

```
var obj = {
  text: 'hello',
  foo: {
    float: 0.5,
    bar: {
      id: 42,
    },
  },
};

console.log(obj.text);
console.log(obj.foo.float);
console.log(obj.foo.bar.id);
```

Comment: hi, sorry this is not possible since I get the path from a data attribute :)
Thank you for your help